# Plot ordered category as colors in geopandas / matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am trying to plot a heatmap of case counts onto the state of São Paulo, Brazil.

This is the variable I want to plot:

```
Name: b, Length: 670, dtype: category
Categories (7, object): [0 < 1-5 < 6-10 < 11-50 < 51-500 < 501-1000 < >501]
```

This is the code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = sp_map.plot(column='b',
                 categorical=True, 
                 legend=True, 
                 figsize=(10,6),
                 markersize=45, 
                 cmap="Reds",
                 ax=ax);
```

And this is the resulting plot:
[image: Cases in São Paulo]

As you can see, the colors were ordered alphabetically, with 6-10 coming after 51-500, even though it is an ordered category. Do you know how I could get that in the right order?

Comment: Isn't it because the category value is a string?

Comment: maybe, but they are ordered in theory. If that is the case, do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: GeoPandas does not support ordered Categorical Dtype (yet). You should use either integers instead of strings or some other kind of alternative way.